# How to change the name of Keys and values of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

So, I'm new to javascript programming and I need to figure it out a way to change the name of keys and values of an object.

Here's the object, I'ts in a variable called `json`:

```
{ 1079: "i",
  1078: "h", 
  843: "g", 
  842: "f",
  841: "e", 
  688: "d",  
  277: "c",
  276: "b",
  70: "a",
}
```

This is the expected `console.log`:

```
{ name: 1079 value: "i",
   name: 1078: value: "h", 
   name: 843: value:"g", 
   name: 842: value:"f",
   name: 841: value:"e", 
   name: 688: value:"d",  
   name: 277: value:"c",
   name: 276: value:"b",
   name: 70: value:"a",
}
```

Anyway, thanks to anyone that can help me.

Comment: First pointer.  `Object.keys(anObject)` will return you an array of all the keys in the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have the same key in an object, but you could take single objects for each pair in an array.

The order is now by the key in numerical order, because of the internal ordering of objects with keys who could be read as indices.

```js
var object = { 1079: "i", 1078: "h", 843: "g", 842: "f", 841: "e", 688: "d", 277: "c", 276: "b", 70: "a" },
    result = Object.entries(object).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work .If you are looking for this.

```js
let obj = {
  1079: "i",
  1078: "h",
  843: "g",
  842: "f",
  841: "e",
  688: "d",
  277: "c",
  276: "b",
  70: "a",
}
let result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [name, value]) => {
  acc.push({
    name,
    value
  })
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var currentObj = { 1079: "i",
      1078: "h", 
      843: "g", 
      842: "f",
      841: "e", 
      688: "d",

      277: "c",
      276: "b",
      70: "a",
    };

    var newObj = Object.keys(currentObj).map(x => { return { name: x, value: currentObj[x] };});
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()`

```js
const data = { 
  1079: "i",
  1078: "h", 
  843: "g", 
  842: "f",
  841: "e", 
  688: "d",
  277: "c",
  276: "b",
  70: "a",
};

function formatObject(obj) {
  const arr = [];
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(x => {        
    arr.push({
      name: x[0],
      value: x[1]
    });
  });
  return arr;
}

const result = formatObject(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take an array, populate it like you want:

```js
var json = { 1079: "i", 1078: "h", 843: "g", 842: "f", 841: "e", 688: "d", 277: "c", 276: "b", 70: "a" }

var arr = [];

for(k in json) arr.push({name:k, value:json[k]})

console.log(arr)
```